# Draw shape from geodatabase using Arcgis JS

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I understood that ArcGIS JavaScript API is used to access and manipulate Services published via ArcGIS Server. Could i be able to retrive shape column from table in Enterprise Geodatabase and display on web using ArcGIS JS API?  How can i approach it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking? If it is published as a service, then yes, you can interact with it through the Javascript API (or the REST API). If it is not published as a service, then you will not be able to access the data from the Javascript API.

Comment: The documentation for the ArcGIS Javascript API has many great examples of how to do this. If you do not have a specific question about some code you have at least tried to run then this question should probably be closed.